# Recover deleted folder form bookmarks bar?

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome

I googled for this, but didn't find an answer.

I removed a folder in Google Chrome's Bookmarks bar. Chrome says nothing when doing this, and I assumed it wouldn't actually delete the data from the Bookmarks manager, just the folder in the Bookmarks bar.

Turns out I was wrong, and now I lost hundred's of URLs.

I closed and restarted Chrome since then, so data is apparently no longer on disk.

Since Google Sync is on by default, it says I have "536 bookmarks", I installed Chrome on another computer, logged on to Google... but the folder is still gone.

I can't believe Chrome doesn't prompt the user with an obvious message for something that important.

Is there somehow a way to recover a folder removed from the Bookmarks bar?

Thank you.

---

Edit: Amazingly, Chrome doesn't 1) provide a way to remove an item from the Bookmarks bar without also deleting it from the Bookmarks list, and 2) doesn't even warn the user of the consequences when doing so!

The only way to recover data is:

- if you haven't closed the browser yet, make a backup of the Bookmarks file, close the browser, replace the now-leaner Bookmarks file with the previous version, and restart Chrome
- if you have closed it, recover the file from your backup. You did backup that file, right? ;-)

Comment: You deleted a folder and didn't think it would delete the contents of the folder?  Your only choice is to attempt to recover the folder itself. There are lots of free tools that might help with that task.  In the future be more careful, and if your bookmarks are important, backup the data.

Comment: No, I deleted a folder *in the Bookmarks bar*, not on disk. For something that important, you would think the application would WARN THE USER that the data would be entirely deleted, not just cosmetically from the interface. Besides Chrome, only keeps a single .BAK and the original is replaced after closing the browser.

Comment: There are extensions that backup your Bookmarks automatically.  As I said you can attempt to recovery the data off the disk, there are lots, of free programs that do that..

Comment: No, it can't be done after closing Chrome: Bookmarks.bak is replaced with the edited Bookmarks, so there's no way to recover the lost items unless we have a backup elsewhere.

Comment: Why would removing a folder ever be cosmetic? Your bookmarks are gone for good.

Comment: I believe in what you say but no browser warns you about this. none of them .

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, accidentally deleted the folders bookmark from google chrome, was actually trying to delete an individual bookmark short-cut but accidentally hit the "favourites" folder - it can happen.

Unfortunately I closed down chrome, and restarted, before searching for advice. Yes, all told me NOT to close down chrome as the favourite folder is then permanently deleted.

Feared everything was lost.

But - one other possibility that I hadn't seen mentioned. One of the things I like about Chrome is that it can be set to synchronize bookmarks with different PCs. I have other PCs which I hadn't booted up today, so decided to check out if this would work. WITHOUT OPENING CHROME on the other PC - navigate to the bookmarks and bookmarks.bak files (under application data). Copy them (via memory stick) to the original PC with the deleted folder; restart Chrome and all should be back to normal. Relief!

Answer (score 0):

If you close Chrome there are already gone...

http://www.howtogeek.com/111784/how-to-recover-accidentally-deleted-bookmarks-in-chrome-firefox/

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Four months worth of URLs gone.

Comment: @OverTheRainbow hey man you can check for your browsing history, it can help ...